# How we can also make that $x_n\in F_n$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $\{e_k\}_{k\ge 1}$ be orthonormal sequence. If for any $x\in \overline{span\{e_k\}_{k=1}^\infty}$, then $$x=\sum_{k=1}^\infty (x,e_k)e_k$$

I have one question about the proof. In proof, it says that for $x\in \overline{span\{e_k\}_{k=1}^\infty}$, one can find $\{x_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ so that $x_n\to x$ and $x_n\in F_n:=span\{e_k\}_{k=1}^n$.

By definition, we can find $\{x_n\}\in span\{e_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ so that $x_n\to x$. But why we can also make that $x_n\in F_n$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Fix it. That is $x_n\to x$.

Comment: Hint: $$span\{e_k\}_{k=1}^\infty =\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty F_n,$$ and $F_n\subset F_m$ for all $n<m.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews So $\{x_n\}\in \cup_{n=1}^\infty F_n$. Then for some $k$, $x_k\in F_l$ for some $l$? Then rewrite the order of sequence, we get ${y_n}$ so that $y_n\in F_n$?

Comment: Don't reuse $n$ like that. Starting with some sequence $x_k$  with $x_k\in F_{n_k},$ you can construct a sequence which looks like, $\{y_n\}=\{0,0,\dots,0,x_1,x_1,\dots,x_1,x_2,\dots,x_2,\dots\}$ and you get that $y_n\in F_n$ and $y_n\to x.$ This is the kind of tedious argument that takes some time to write out rigorously. Basically, you start with $n_1-1$ zeros. Then $\max(n_1+1,n_2)-n_1$ values of $x_1,$ etc. take one or more instances of $x_k$ until your next index is at least as big as  $n_{k+1}.$